# How can I use Firebase in a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, firebase, api

I already took the APK of the application, but the part of the use of the API did not work. I investigated and I have to do a process to add firebase to my application. How can I do it step by step. I already read the documentation but it doesn't help me much.

The idea is that the API part works, that I can get the information, but the process is complicated...

Comment: What API you are referring to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The API is created by oneself, in firebase

Answer (score 0):

No process is needed. The way to fix it was: Go to *android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml* Add the line uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/ On the line before